# How to config apache 1 connection per user and banwidth 50mb/s per user

Tags: apache-2.2

How to  config apache 1 connection per user and banwidth 50mb/s per user

Answer (score 0):

I would look at [mod_bandwidth](http://www.cohprog.com/mod_bandwidth.html) and [mod_limitipconn](http://dominia.org/djao/limitipconn.html). I've used the latter and it seems to work well enough with Apache 1.3. Be aware that modern browsers can initiate multiple connections when accessing a web site. I found that if I set the limit to lower than 10 connections per user then images/CSS files would sometimes not be loaded. You'll have to choose a number based on your application.

Also make sure your server/connection can handle 50mb/s (bits or bytes?) per user.

Comment: I wouldn't be worried about bits or bytes while we're still talking about milli-something... Now MB vs Mb, that's more meaningful.